# Sentences without topic particles?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particles, word-usage

how common is it for there to be sentences like 「私、死んでるよ！」or 「これ、怖い」？ is it super informal? any guidelines on when to speak like this?

Comment: I certainly would be 怖い is some one said 私、死んでるよ

Comment: @jacoballens Do you think 私、死んでるよ means 'I'm dying'? It actually means 'I'm dead'.

Comment: i actually did think that hahaha. how would you say “i’m dying” then?

Answer (score 5):

Omission of は/を (and sometimes に) is ubiquitous in casual conversations, including not-so-serious business conversations with your colleagues.

> - これ何？
> - ペン貸して。
> - お昼食べました？
> - どこ行く？

But if you think naturalness is important, note that something like 私 is usually also omitted along with は.

> - 死んでる！ He's/She's/I'm dead! (after you found someone was dead, or after you woke up to find yourself transformed into a zombie/ghost)

Comment: I guess it doesn't really change the meaning so much but would you say を or に was omitted from お昼食べました?

Comment: @user3856370 This お昼 means "lunch", so を has been omitted.